# Условное изменение запроса в LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Мне надо взять `ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value` продуктов, если `ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value == 0` надо брать все

```
var products = _dbProducts.GetAllDbSet()
            .Take(ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value)
            .Include(p => p.Supplier)
            .Include(p => p.Category)
            .AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: это stackoverflow на русском, переведите вопрос, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как мы получаем `IQueryable`, можно составить следующий запрос, который выгрузит только необходимое количество:

```
var query = _dbProducts.GetAllAsQueryable();
query = _configuration.ProductMaxLenght.Value == 0 ?
        query : query.Take(_configuration.ProductMaxLenght.Value);

var products = query
.Include(p => p.Supplier)
.Include(p => p.Category);
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно поступить просто:

```
int value = ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value;

if (value == 0)
{
    var products = _dbProducts.GetAllDbSet()
        .Include(p => p.Supplier)
        .Include(p => p.Category)
        .AsNoTracking();
}
else
{
    var products = _dbProducts.GetAllDbSet()
        .Take(value)
        .Include(p => p.Supplier)
        .Include(p => p.Category)
        .AsNoTracking();
}
```

Обратите внимание, что в запрос нельзя передавать выражение `ConfigurationService.ProductMaxLenght.Value`, а только простое значение (`value`).

Однако, linq-запросы бывают весьма длинными и такая запись будет слишком громоздкой. Поэтому составим запрос на лету:

```
IQueryable<T> products = _dbProducts.GetAllDbSet();

if (value != 0)
{
    products = products.Take(value);
}

products = products
    .Include(p => p.Supplier)
    .Include(p => p.Category)
    .AsNoTracking();
```

`T` - подставьте нужный тип сущности.